# create a variable list from local macro list (findname)

Tags: variables, stata, local, stata-macros, findname

I have lists of variables in local macros that I would like to use in a command, e.g.:

```
    local a int1 int2 num1 num2 bin1 bin2 ...
    local b int3 int4 bin3 num3  ...
```

Here variable `num*` `int*` and `bin*` are numeric, integer and binary respectively.

I want to run a `foreach` loop over of the variables in local `a' and` b', but only those that are integer-valued, namely, `int1, int2, int3`, ...

For this, I use `findname` command created by Nick Cox to find variables that are integer-valued, saving a list of corresponding variable names in a local macro. But I do not want to run it for all variables in a dataset but only for subsets of variables (designated in locals `a`, `b`, and so on), and then use the list in a subsequent command.

So for a list of integer variables in local `a' and` b' being local `a_int' and` b_int', I want to use is as below:

```
    foreach var of varlist `a_int' `b_int'{
        whatever command
    }
```

Comment: Well, if `foo` is in a list you can create a new variable `foo_qualifies` as `gen foo_qualifies = 1` which is 1 in all observations. And so on for other variables. I can't see why that is any use over and above what `findname` provides. Why do you want this?

Comment: @Makiko What would you want your indicator variable to be if you have, let's say, two variables x1 and x2, and one observation where x1 = 1, x2=3.5? I think your question would benefit from a minimal example of your data together with your wanted output. See also the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for info on how best to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need the intersection of two lists stored in local macros. To do this you can use the macro extended functions to manipulate lists: see `help macrolists`.

```
// Setup
local a x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
local b x4 x5 x6 x7 x8
local int x2 x3 x6

// Get intersection of variable lists and integer list
local a_int : list a & int
local b_int : list b & int

// Put a_int and b_int together and drop possible duplicates
local ab_int `a_int' `b_int'
local ab_int_uniq : list uniq ab_int

// Do something
foreach var of varlist `ab_int_uniq' {
    * do something
}
```